# "And" between last and second last cite using the \footcites command and authoryear-icomp

Tags: biblatex

When using `\footcites` all cites are equally separated by `\multicitedelim`. However, I would like the last two cites to be separated by "and". With certain limitations, this is possible with `\textcites` and a workaround would be to use `\footnote{\textcites{}.}`. Strangely, this only works for two cites. If three or more cites are included ", and" and not "and" is produced. Considering this, I was wondering what would have to be done to obtain the desired result using `\footcites`.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = {George D. Greenwade},
    title   = {The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})},
    year    = {1993},
    journal = {TUGBoat},
    volume  = {14},
    number  = {3},
    pages   = {342--351}
}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
    title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
    year      = {1993},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    address   = {Reading, Massachusetts}
}

@book{Knuth86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
How it should look like.\footnote{\cites{goossens93}{greenwade93} and \cite{Knuth86}.}

How it should not look like.\footcites{goossens93}{greenwade93}[and][]{Knuth86}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice first question.  Just a remark: it is better to use `{...}` (see your book Knuth86) instead of `"..."` (first and second bib entry) in your bib file.  BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily, `biblatex` already provides everything we need for this (so much so that I am surprised this is not actually already implemented - other `\multi...delim`s already have `\final...delim` versions).

We just need to make use of `biblatex`'s  `\iflastcitekey` test to determine whether we are at the last item, and if so slightly change the definition of `\multicitedlim`

```
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{%
  \iflastcitekey
    {\addspace\bibstring{and}}
    {\addsemicolon}%
  \space}
```

That's it!

This will not work in all comer cases (especially in case of compressed citations), in these cases it might be better to use `\textcite` in the footnote directly. Like

```
\footnote{\textcite{geer,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}}
```

Depending on your stance on the Oxford comma you will need to tweak `\finalandcomma`/`\finalandsemicolon`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{%
  \iflastcitekey
    {\addspace\bibstring{and}}
    {\addsemicolon}%
  \space}

\begin{document}
How it should look like.\footcites{geer}{sigfridsson}{worman} vs this\footcites{geer,sigfridsson,worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The test only works with non-compact citation labels. Citation labels that form part of a sentence should be generated only with `\textcite` or `\textcites`; the solution here should be to invoke one of these citation commands in `\footnote` and add something like `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\renewcommand{\finalandcomma}{}}` to the preamble (or redefine `\textcitedelim`).

Comment: @Audrey Thanks for the comment! I had feared something like this would be the case. (I hoped though, no-one would notice `;-)`). I will update the answer a bit with your suggestions.