# Declare multicite command with just part of the citation in parentheses

Tags: biblatex

**Update:** I can get the result I want by doing this:

```
\newcommand*{\textapud}[2]{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1} apud \citeauthor{#2}, \citeyear{#2})}
```

But there are a few problems. First of all it doesn't look very nice and I think I could do better. Second of all I can't specify a `prenote` and a `postnote` for each of the two entries (I think there might be a way to add that possibility to this command, but I couldn't get it to work yet). And lastly, I can't use the `bibstring` command – the "apud" text is hardcoded there.

---

My question is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213185/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-cite-two-things-connected-by-a-joining-word-wi/261596#261596), except I want to put only part of the citation in parenthesis.

---

I'm trying to write a `biblatex` style and citations should be like

> "this" (DOE, 2015)

or, when citing the author in the middle of the text, like this:

> according to BLOW (2016).

So far so good, I managed to do that. Then, when citing one author based on another author, it has to be like

> "this" (DOE, 2015 apud BLOW, 2016).

Based on moewe's answer to [the question I mentioned above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213185/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-cite-two-things-connected-by-a-joining-word-wi/261596#261596), I managed to do that too (my code is in the MWE below), but now I need the version for doing it in the middle of the text, like this:

> according to DOE (2015 apud BLOW, 2016).

And I don't have a clue how to do that. Any ideas?

---

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@abook{doe,
    author = {John Doe},
    year = {2015}}
@article{blow,
    author = {Joe Blow},
    year = {2016}}
@article{smith,
    author = {Jim Smith},
    year = {2016}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}

\newcommand{\addapud}{%
  \renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{%
    \ifnumequal{\value{multicitecount}}{\value{multicitetotal}}
      {\space\bibstring{apud}}
      {\addsemicolon}%
    \space}%
  \renewcommand*{\textcitedelim}{%
    \ifnumequal{\value{multicitecount}}{\value{multicitetotal}}
      {\addspace\bibstring{apud}}
      {\addsemicolon}%
    \space}%
}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\apud}[\addapud\mkbibparens]
    {\@apud}
    {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}

% This is to allow that second option down there
% in which the first author isn't in the .bib file.
\DeclareCiteCommand{\@apud}
    {\iffieldundef{prenote}
        {}
        {\printfield[uppercase]{prenote}
        \addspace\bibstring{apud}\addspace}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}
    {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

% \DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\textapud}% HOW??

\begin{document}

  \apud{doe}{blow}{smith}

  \apud[Batman][]{smith}

\end{document}
```

PS: I didn't add the `bibstring` or the code to make names and fields uppercase because I thought it wasn't relevant.

PS2: The command doesn't have to account for the possibility of more than two authors, like the regular `\apud` does.

Comment: @cfr Ah, It's the first thing I said in my question, but I guess it wasn't clear enough, now I edited the "question above" part to link to the question too.

Comment: Sorry. I somehow missed the fact that you had a link earlier in the question. Apologies. (But it is always good to hit readers like me over the head with important information, so your edit is appreciated!)

Comment: I would test whether the value of the counter is `1` as well as if it equals the total and then execute the relevant code conditionally. I.e. if counter is 1 then ... else (if counter is total then ... else ...).

Comment: @cfr I'm trying to work with that, but I only manage to add stuff in between two cited entries, so I don't know how to open the parentheses in between the first author's name and the first year.

Comment: @cfr My `@apud` cite command there uses the `cite` bib macro… I'm thinking I could define another macro that opens the parenthesis at the right place and then another that closes it at the right place, but then I don't know how to make the multicite command use one or the other conditionally, I've tried checking the `citecount` for that, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Note that the code *is* relevant if somebody needs it to reproduce the problem. Without the `bibstring`s, I don't see how the code can be compiled to reproduce your situation.

Comment: @cfr Well, without the definition the `bibstring` command just prints "apud" in bold, I thought it was enough for testing… we could even have the "apud" string hardcoded there, the main thing is that it shows up in the right place and I think my code allows us to test that. I could add the `bibstring` code, but I think it has to be in its own `.lbx` file, doesn't it? Then it seems like a lot of trouble to add it here and link it correctly to the `authoryear` style… I don't even know how to do that and it seems like it'll make the example a lot more complicated with little gain.

Comment: If this is a recurrent thing with this entry *but* a relatively unfrequent one in your entire bibliography, maybe you could use a `related` field, i.e. add the main entry's citekey in the "*apud* entry". Then modify the citation style to incorporate related entries within parentheses and cite just the "*apud* entry". This requires running `biber` twice.

Comment: Or create a fake `\multicite` which takes two (or more) arguments and turns `#2` into a related field of `#1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imho the title of your question is wrong: You don't have a multicite here. What you really want is to add a \cite in the comment of another \cite. The logical input would imho be

```
 \textcite[{apud \cite[15]{smith}}]{Doe}
```

But this input is not allowed as you can't nest citations.

What you should do instead depends on the concrete case.

I wouldn't try to tweak multicite. While it can work it doesn't look sane to misuse it for this case. I also wouldn't overdo -- consider how often you really need it, and if a manual solution (which often is more flexible) isn't the best solution.

You could add a `related` field pointing to smith and write a cite command that use this field. But this will not allow you to add a prenote or postnote to smith.

The alternative is to do what you already suggesting: Write a fake cite command `\textapud` that gives what you want. You can improve it with optional arguments (you will perhaps want to change the placement of the pre- and postnotes):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}

\NewBibliographyString{apud}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{apud=apud}

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\textapud}{o o m o o m}{%
 \citeauthor{#3}  
 \mkbibparens{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
     {\citeyear{#3}}
     {\citeyear[#1]{#3}}%
   }
   {%
    \citeyear[#1][#2]{#3}%
   }   
  \IfNoValueTF{#5}
   {%
    \IfNoValueTF{#4}
     {\cite[\blx@imc@bibxstring{apud}][]{#6}}
     {\cite[\blx@imc@bibxstring{apud}][#4]{#6}}%
   }
   {%
    \cite[\blx@imc@bibxstring{apud} #4][#5]{#6}%
   }%   
  }}
\makeatother 


\begin{document}

\textapud[see][15]{doe}[blub][20]{smith}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! The only thing is I'm adding it to a `biblatex` style file and then I'd have to do `\RequirePackage{xparse}` right there at the `.cbx` file… is that a good idea? I don't know anything about LaTeX3 and, well, about pretty much anything at all, I'm just trying to piece stuff together to replace an old `bibtex` style.