# Apud: which one is the best way to do it?

Tags: citing

[Daniel Valencia C.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380181/remove-brackets-from-a-single-citation) did the following in 2017:

```
\citep[\textit{apud} \citep{Key2}]{Key1}
```

There is a better way to do apud than this one?

[This blog post](https://jufajardini.wordpress.com/2013/11/26/latex-citar-autores-citados-por-outro-autor-apud/) by Juliana Fajardini from 2013 mentions an `\apud` command:

```
\apud{autor_indireto}{autor_direto}
```

But I could not reproduce it on Overleaf. It gives me an error for command not recognized.

Comment: The blog post you've linked talks about using the `abntex2cite` package to do citations in the ABNT format. The `\apud` macro comes from this package, that's why it won't work unless you `\usepackage{abntex2cite}`. Nowadays though it's probably better to use `\usepackage[backend = biber, style = abnt]{biblatex}` for citations in the ABNT style.

Comment: @DanielDiniz I don't care much about using ABNT-style citations, I just want to apud easily in a way that is semantically and syntatically correct.

Comment: There are a number of other questions on the cite about using 'apud', see https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=apud. Some of them indeed define commands similar to the one you found in the blog post. It depends on your setup (as always, so it would be helpful if you provide a full MWE), but for example a BibLaTeX approach is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308113/declare-multicite-command-with-just-part-of-the-citation-in-parentheses.