# Biblatex: Change delimiter in compressed citation list

Tags: biblatex

I want to do something similar to this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213185/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-cite-two-things-connected-by-a-joining-word-wi), which adds a word between two citations. When I have a range of citations (more than 2 in a row), it like to change the hyphen to the word "to". For some reason changing the \compcitedelim doesn't work for me. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\title{Test}
\author{T. Est }
\date{November 2019}

\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\bibstring{to}}
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\bibstring{to}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Test \cite{key1, key2, key3}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The bibliography, test.bib, has three entries

```
@misc{key1,
    author = {Author, O.},
    title = {The First Citation},
    year = {2019},
    howpublished = {Unpublished},
}

@misc{key2,
    author = {Author, T.},
    title = {The Second Citation},
    year = {2019},
    howpublished = {Unpublished},
}

@misc{key3,
    author = {Author, T.},
    title = {The Third Citation},
    year = {2019},
    howpublished = {Unpublished},
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dash (`\bibrangedash`) is hard-coded in the bibmacro `cite:dump` ([ll. 87-99 of `numeric-comp.cbx` in `biblatex` v3.13a](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/bcc7970e4020533cf9cf430b222b5699c1bd92f1/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric-comp.cbx#L87-L99)), but it is possible to replace it with a customisable macro, `\comprangedelim` say

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{to}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  to = {to},
}

\newcommand*{\comprangedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{to}\space}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:dump}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcnta}}{0}
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcnta}}{1}
       {\comprangedelim}
       {\multicitedelim}%
     \bibhyperref[\cbx@lastkey]{%
       \ifdef\cbx@lastprefix
         {\printtext[labelprefix]{\cbx@lastprefix}}
         {}%
       \printtext[labelnumber]{\cbx@lastnumber}}}
    {}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcnta}{0}%
  \global\undef\cbx@lastprefix}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Test [1 to 3].]

---

`\compcitedelim` is only used by the `-comp` styles of the `authortitle` and `authoryear` families. There it separates citations by the same author (where the author name is dropped).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}

\cite{sigfridsson,worman}

\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\addspace \textcolor{red}{C}\space}
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addspace \textcolor{blue}{M}\space}

\cite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}

\cite{sigfridsson,worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Knuth 1984, 1986//Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Worman 2002//Knuth 1984 C 1986//Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998 M Worman 2002]

Comment: Thanks. So what purpose does \compcitedelim have?

Comment: @an4 It is used in other styles (`authoryear-comp`, `authortitle-comp` and friends) and separates citations where the `comp` feature was used and the author name dropped. See the edit please.